# Cocoa documnt based app does not do anything on Command W

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like it to close on <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> as per the standard.  There is a close button on window and it's enabled so I'm not sure what is eating the close command keyboard shortcut.

The content view is a webview if that makes any difference.

I've implemented `windowWillClose` and `windowShouldClose` but none of them are hit during debugging when pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the File menu at the top of the screen flash when you press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>?  That might indicate whether something is eating the key event before it goes to the normal responder chain.  For example, I believe it is possible for some javascript in your webview could be eating the event.

Normally the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> is sent to the firstResponder (usually the control where keyboard focus is) and then along the responder chain.  This document might be helpful: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW10

Some things to try:

Make a text field outside your webview and see if <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> works when that text field has focus.  That might implicate the webview.

Turn on `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled`.
This produces lots of output, but can show you exactly what methods are called after you press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>.

Comment: I don't have a file menu item only MainMenu as File doesn't make any sense in this app? I'll put in the text field and let you know

Comment: Is there a Close menu item at all?  Maybe you deleted it when you removed the File menu.  Most document based apps have a file menu.

Comment: now that I added a new File menue and just took the close menu out to main menu it is working... but why is that the case?? I had also tried to implement performKeyEquivalent and performClose but they were not being called

Comment: There’s nothing intrinscally special about Command ⌘-W. However, it is the keyboard shortcut for stock File > Close Window. By removing this menu item, you’ve removed the keyboard shortcut as well.

Comment: Cmd-W is just a shortcut for that menu item, so the menu item needs to exist and have its key equivalent set.  Notice also that users can remap keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences, so you wouldn't want Cmd-W to be hard coded somewhere in the system.

Comment: @user549164: If a File menu doesn't make sense for your app, you should move Close to the Window menu.